# Update QA environment - workflow manager databases

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-manager

We have a QA SharePoint 2013 environment we want to refresh from PROD. Workflow manager is already configured and working. I completed the refresh of the content databases but realized the 2013 workflow instances were orphaned. Does anyone know which of the Workflow manager databases also need to be copied to our QA? The WFInstanceManagementDB seems to be one (possibly containing the instances) but there are also the WFManagementDB, WFResourceManagementDB, SbManagementDB, SBMessageContainer01, SbGatewayDatabase that appear to be associated with WFM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make it work by making scope restore. Follow the procedures from SM for Disaster Recovery. This article also is good with step by step what needs to be done

[Workflow Manager Disaster Recovery](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29158.workflow-manager-disaster-recovery.aspx)

Comment: There is nothing easy about the WFM, we moved back to to SP2010 WFS. We had so many failures with it and spend endless hours with Premier Support to get back on track.

Comment: I agree. I am not a big fan of it. I remember banging my head just trying to get it installed. I would love to get rid of it but we have so many WFs in the platform now. We are going to purchase K2 and hopefully get rid of WFM eventually. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the end, we just decided to republish the workflows from SharePoint Designer. We really didn't need all of them because it is a UAT environment, we just needed the more complicated ones for testing something we are doing.